# Restart IIS if new dll dropped in bin?

Tags: iis

Do I have to restart IIS if I drop a new DLL in the bin of my virtual directory?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No you do not have to, the application will recycle, but an IISReset is NOT needed

Answer (score 4):

No you don't have to restart IIS. However, your worker process will automatically recycle itself.

Answer (score 1):

If your application is an ASP.NET app, I believe the AppDomain will restart, but the worker process (w3wp.exe) will NOT.  For most purposes, an AppDomain reset is sufficient to clear the state but for some (generally to do with unmanaged DLLs having been loaded in the process) this may not be sufficient.  In these cases, IISRESET will work.